# Am I obligated to use this in php?

Tags: php, oop, this

When accessing class members from member functions, am I obligated to use `$this`? Or I can just mention member names?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `$this` differentiates between object members and variables that are simply local vars. e.g.

```
object x {
   public $z = 'hello';
   function y() {
      $z = 'there';
      echo $z; // there
      echo $this->z; // hello
   }
   function z() {
       echo $z; // undefined variable/warning/error.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to `$this`. It is mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you must use `$this` to reference class members. You can also use `self::` to reference static class members. Without `$this` you can only reference local variables, meaning variables declared in the current function, or global variables declared using `global`

See [PHP: Classes and Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) for more info on PHP classes

Answer (score 2):

In a PHP class, you can have static member variable or instance member variable.

If it is instance member variable, you need to access it with `$this->inst_variable`
If it is static member variable, then with `self::$my_static`

If you are not using $this or self, it will be considered as local variable.